# Setting z-index of ListView in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing my own version of auto-complete feature in my Xamarin Forms 5 app where I display suggestions to user's entry in a `ListView`.

The problem I'm running into is that I don't want `ListView` to push down succeeding `Entry` controls in the form. Instead, I'd like the `ListView` to be above them. Is there a way to set the z-index of `ListView`.

```
<Entry
   Text="{Binding SearchText}"
   Placeholder="Position you're applying for e.g. Director of Marketing"/>

<ListView
   ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}"
   IsVisible="{Binding ShowSuggestions}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding PositionName}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<Entry
   Text="{Binding Salary}"
   Placeholder="Desired salary"/>
```

In this example, I don't want the "Salary" `Entry` box to be pushed down when user gets suggestions.

P.S. I have a view model for this page so I'd like to handle things in the view model if I can as opposed to events in code behind for the page.

Comment: What do you mean by to be above? How will you be able to focus on Entry after that? What is the parent of the controls you showed ?

Comment: is this inside a StackLayout?  You probably want to use a Grid or AbsoluteLayout so you can position the LIstView on top of the other controls when it is visible

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the "Salary" Entry box to be pushed down when user gets
> suggestions.

Yes, you can use `grid` to achieve this function, and set the Height of `RowDefinition` to `*` for the second row.

Please refer to the xaml code:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Entry  Text="{Binding SearchText}"  Placeholder="Position you're applying for e.g. Director of Marketing"/>

   <ListView Grid.Row="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}"
      IsVisible="{Binding ShowSuggestions}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding PositionName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>


        <Entry Text="{Binding Salary}"  Placeholder="Desired salary" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout to achieve the desired result:

```
<RelativeLayout x:Name="mainLayout">
        <Entry
            x:Name="searchEntry"
            Text="{Binding SearchText}"
            Placeholder="Position you're applying for e.g. Director of Marketing"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1.0}"
            Focused="SearchEntry_Focused"
            Unfocused="SearchEntry_Unfocused"/>

        <Frame 
            x:Name="searchList"
            Padding="0"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1.0}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=searchEntry, Property=X}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=searchEntry, Property=Y, Constant=50}">
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}"
                IsVisible="{Binding ShowSuggestions}"
                ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding PositionName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Frame>

        <Entry
            Text="{Binding Salary}"
            Placeholder="Desired salary"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1.0}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=searchEntry, Property=X}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=searchEntry, Property=Y, Constant=50}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Elements are linked to each other using constraints. Please read [RelativeLayout Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) for more info.
I've wrapped ListView using a Frame for styling, you can also group together with the Entry to make it a reusable component.

And in your show/hide logic (Focused/Unfocused/ItemTapped or whatever) you need to call:

```
mainLayout.RaiseChild(searchList); // so list gets on top of other elements.
mainLayout.LowerChild(searchList); // list goes behind so you can interact with other elements again.
```

P.S. From [RelativeLayout Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout):

> Avoid using a RelativeLayout whenever possible. It will result in the CPU having to perform significantly more work.

> A RelativeLayout that uses relative values can position and size children so that they don't fit within the bounds of the layout.

So use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

A `DataTrigger` can be used with [`Layout.RaiseChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.raisechild?view=xamarin-forms)/[`Layout.LowerChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.lowerchild?view=xamarin-forms) in a `TriggerAction`, sending the layout child to the front or back of the visual stack, respectively:

```
xmlns:ta="clr-namespace:My.TriggerActions;assembly=..."
...
<Entry ...
  <Entry.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry"
                 Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=IsVisible}"
                 Value="True">
      <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <ta:RaiseTriggerAction />
      </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <ta:LowerTriggerAction />
      </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Entry.Triggers>
```

TriggerActions:

```
namespace My.TriggerActions
{
  public class RaiseTriggerAction : TriggerAction<View>
  {
    protected override void Invoke(View view)
    {
        var layout = view.Parent as Layout;
        Debug.WriteLineIf(layout != null, GetType().ToString());
        layout?.RaiseChild(view);
    }
  }

  public class LowerTriggerAction : TriggerAction<View>
  {
    protected override void Invoke(View view)
    {
        var layout = view.Parent as Layout;
        Debug.WriteLineIf(layout != null, GetType().ToString());
        layout?.LowerChild(view);
    }
  }
}
```